# Should we have a Slack tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Questions like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/1134219/setting-up-slack-alerts-for-monit-monitoring-mysql) seem to be missing a "Slack" tag because we don't have a [slack](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/slack) tag on ServerFault.  This would be a logical addition to our tags since it is commonly used in many IT shops these days.  Getting alerts in Slack seems like it fits with best practices used in commercial environments.  Are there any guidelines that this tag wouldn't pass?

Answer (score 2):

Just create it if you feel the need for it. You have [more than enough reputation to create tags](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges).

There are already [more than 100 questions](https://serverfault.com/search?q=slack+is%3Aquestion) containing the word `slack`. I'd say it's warranted.

Comment: Thank you.  Most of those are using "slack" in some other sense of the word, but I've [added the slack tag to 4 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/slack).